# Using contains method in java

Tags: java

I have converted my string array to `Array` using `Arrays.toString(array)` method.
But still my string looks like an array in this way. `[Monday, Sunday, Tuesday]`. Okie thats not the issue. I have another array which is also converted to `String`.

Say `[Monday, Tuesday]`. Now this is my problem. When I try to use contains method in these arrays it is not working. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Arrays#toString(Object[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])):

> The value returned by this method is equal to the value that would be returned by `Arrays.asList(a).toString()`, unless a is `null`, in which case `"null"` is returned.

and [String#contains(CharSequence)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Example:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday" };
String string = Arrays.toString(stringArray);
boolean result = string.contains("Tuesday");
```

But I would recommend:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday" };
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
boolean result = stringList.contains("Tuesday");
```

See [Arrays#asList(T...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and [ArrayList#contains(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to check if one array got (contains) content of another array without using the contains method

```
String[] string1 = new String[] { "Monday", "Sunday", "Tuesday" };
String[] string2 = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday" };

for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < string2.length; j++) {
        if (string1[i].equals(string2[j])) {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```